# Need php template help and clean url help

Tags: php, templates, clean-urls

I'm new to PHP and web development in general, but have been a programmer for 5 years.  I'm trying to work on my own website from scratch using Notepad to edit my PHP files and WAMP for my server.  I'm able to view my files fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox, but not IE (which we all know IE isn't the greatest) because I'm using some HTML5 stuff.  Anyways, I have an Includes folder that holds my files for my header, menu and footer.  I have an index.php file that includes these files and displays them fine.  In the center of the page is where I want the content.  To try and keep clean urls, I made quite a few folders and put this same index.php file in there (e.g. Profile/index.php, Forums/index.php, etc.).  I did this so when I went to localhost/mysite/profile/ it showed me the template I wanted to use.  However, there has got to be a better way to use the template and a better way to have clean urls.  I'm not currently hosting this site anywhere so I don't know if I'll have access to the htaccess file (not even sure what it is honestly, just seen it mentioned), but I was curious of having the folder structure (one folder for each menu item) is a normal or ok practice?  I was also curious if there is a way to use the index.php without having to copy and paste it every time I make a small change.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the index.php file is not really the way I would go. It seems messy and there are a few other options. If you want the urls to be clean and search engine friendly you should really have a look at [url rewriting using .htaccess](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

You're saying that you're not sure if you will have a server with "access to the htaccess file" but if you can upload files you can always upload a .htaccess file as well -- the problem is that the web server is not always using them or might not have mod_rewrite enabled. In this case you can get your urls on the format of `http://www.example.com/index.php?u=/Profile/foo` (this is also my preferred way to handle url rewrites).

In your index.php just make sure to read the requested url parameter passed by mod_rewrite and include whatever files in the folder that you need. Actually, you don't even need a "physical" folder structure, you might want to implement it using classes or something like that. (I'm sure I would).

I would really recommend that you go have a look at a good PHP framework, [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) for example. Even if you decide to code everything from scratch, you would still learn *a lot* about best practices for url handling, databases, the MVC pattern, template engines, database abstraction layers and PHP coding in general.

Comment: Yeah, well I'm not sure if where I'm going to be hosting it will allow me access to that file.  I know there might be other sites out there that will allow me access to it, but since it's just for fun and it'll be on some cheap host, I'm not sure yet.  But I'll keep that link for future use if I'm allowed access to it.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, my coworker who sits right next to me uses codeigniter (just started really) said that there are a lot of frameworks out there already that do what I'm trying to do.  However, because I'm an engineer at heart, I always try to do something from scratch first so I better understand it.  Also, I'm not that great with Eclipse for some reason.  I may have to take a week off of work so I can dedicate some time to learning it, and CodeIgniter.  Thanks.

Comment: You really don't need Eclipse to use CI. I'm no big Eclipse fan myself. I really understand how you're feeling about doing stuff from scratch - that doesn't mean that you can't have a look at how others have solved things, right? I did things the hard way for a couple of years before I had a good look at some frameworks -- it was really an epiphany. I hope you'll enjoy it as much as I did :)

Comment: Ok, I'll have to see how to use CI without eclipse.  I used the MVC pattern at my previous job for about 4 months, working on an ASP.Net project, but I figured the engine took the template and did what it needed to do. Since I'm still new to PHP, I don't know it's ins and outs.  Shoot, I'm still having a hard time with position, overflow and float in html.  :)

Comment: Actually, since you seem to be both familiar with MVC and a good programmer, it might be nice just to skim through some of the [CI user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/) for ideas and inspiration.

Comment: lol.  You mention that as I'm doing it.  However, I dislike how they are very vague on the installation instructions.  Symfony, from what I was reading, showed you what the folder structure should be like after you unzip the files, CI does not.  I guess it's just learning through trial and error.  :)  I probably won't have an answer for my original question until I've had time to investigate these options.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: :D
Well, if I remember it correctly. You just unzip it and the directory structure is there. You put your application specific stuff under ./application

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on templating I suggest using an existing platform like [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/), [Zend Framework,](http://framework.zend.com/) or [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). Smarty is probably the easiest to get going with and it is (almost) purely for templating. Whereas Symfony and Zend Framework are big packages with lots of bells and whistles.

If I was going to be doing pure templating I would look at Smarty. I use Zend Framework for just about all my current PHP projects now but it has a pretty steep learning curve. Your first couple weeks will be frustrating.

As far as URLs go, `.htaccess` is probably the preferred method (at least in my book). Zend Framework and Symfony both have kind of default URL writing style that looks like `http://host/controller/action` where controller would be **Profile** or **Forums**. You wouldn't necessarily have to see `host/profile/index`, it could be `host/profile` or `host/profile/edit`, where edit is the action being performed.

Comment: Yeah, I need to investigate the htaccess some more, I'm reading the link someone gave me above.  However, as far as the templating go, what do those packages actually do?  Meaning, what would the inards of the files look like for using the template.  My idea of using a template is like how in ASP there is a template and they have place holders for <ASP:ContentHolder> or something like that.  However, I believe the engine handles the html output, but I honestly don't know.  I'll take a look at those packages though.  Thanks.

Comment: Smarty will be your easiest for pure templating because it doesn't require you to implement an MVC structure (though I highly recommend it). It does have tags that allow you to hold content, use variables, and loop through collections as well as a lot of other things.

Comment: Well, I'm reading the guide for Symfony now because there were some things that caught my eye.  It's just a long read.  :)

Answer (score 0):

your answer is the htaccess file, is converts the 'folder structure' to $_GET value's

for example,

if you're in website.com/Profile/ you can write an htaccess line that will convert that into website.com/index.php?folder=Profile

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ index.php?folder=$1 [NC,L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^/(.*).html$ index.php?folder=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Well, that's the thing, I want the folder structure to be like website.com/profile/.  Ideally, say I want to see userid's 1234 profile, I'd want the url to be website.com/profile/1234/.

Comment: so repeat the process
<pre>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?folder=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/.html$ index.php?folder=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
</pre>